# Using Contains() on Collection of Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I'm still learning LINQ and I have a collection of anonymous types obtained using something like the following. [mycontext] is a placeholder for my actual data source:

```
var items = from item in [mycontext]
            select new { item.col1, item.col2, item.col3 };
```

How can I use `items.Contains()` to determine if `items` contains a matching value?

The value I am searching for is *not* an anonymous type. So I will need to write my own compare logic, preferably as a lambda expression.

Comment: While you are learning, grab a copy of LinqPad. It is a really useful tool with lots of good examples.

Comment: @Mr Moose: Got it last week. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer to use a predicate then you're probably better off using [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) rather than `Contains`:

```
bool exists = items.Any(x => x.col1 == "foo"
                             && x.col2 == "bar"
                             && x.col3 == 42);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the LINQ `Any()` method:

```
if (items.Any(i => i.col1 == myOtherThing.Value))
{
    // Effectively Contains() == true
}
```

Comment: This version addressed my situation, where the logic is to match `col1` and not the entire `item`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the "Any" method with a predicate.

```
bool exists = items.Any( i => {logic} );
```